# How to make stuff like $('#div').myscript{(var1:1,var2:2)}?

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the poor question, but I don't know what it is. 
Recently I have seen a guy who sells his jquery script and I noticed that the functionality is based in this:

```
$('#div').hisScript{(
var1 : example,
var2 : example2
)};
```

So the code in the script applies to that div. My question is: What is this? And how to? 
I think is some type of encapsulation or something like that. But I don't find anything about (probably because I don't know how it is named) it in internet. Could anyone give me a example?

Comment: What is so tough in that? that's just an object generally used for settings of the plugin

Comment: BTW, you have the curly braces and parenthesis inversed (or there's really some magic)

Comment: @dystroy Include that in your answer as well....

Answer (score 3):

This is called a jQuery plugin.

[It's very easy to do](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). Once you have imported jQuery, you can simply do

```
$.fn.hisScript = function(opt){
    // do stuff, this is the jquery object
}
```

Basically, it works because `$.fn` is an alias for `$.prototype` and `$` is the constructor of jQuery objects.

A simple example :

```
$.fn.reverseText = function(opt){
  this.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), txt = $this.text();
    if (txt.indexOf(opt.having)!=-1) {
      $this.text(txt.split('').reverse().join(''));
    }
 });
}

// reverse the text of all paragraph containing 'sentence'
$('p').reverseText({having:'sentence'});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ireHIJo/1/)

Note that

- you have the curly braces and parenthesis inverted in your question.
- it's generally a good idea to iterate over `this`, even if you don't immediately think that you'll use your "plugin" for collections having more than one element

Comment: Thanks for the answers. And especially thanks @dystroy, that is what I'm exactly interested to learn, had not idea about that! (and sorry for the brackets and braces, I've made ​​a mess)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you are asking about .hisScript, or how he is passing in parameters. Since another user posted an answer about hisScript being a jquery plugin, I'll touch on passing in the object. I find a lot of people new to javascript get confused about it, and this simple example seems to clear the confusion a lot.

Think of this:

```
$('#div').hisScript({
var1 : "someString",
var2 : 123123
});
```

As this

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.var1 = "someString";
obj.var2 = 123123;

$('#div').hisScript(obj);
```